# Returning Unicode Name With Code Point

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, unicode

I know how to return a Unicode character from a code point.  That's not what I'm after.  What I want to know is how to return the name associated with a particular code point.  For example, The code point for  is 1F340.  And its name is FOUR LEAF CLOVER.  Is it possible for us to return this name with its code point?  I've read about 100 topics involving Unicode.  But I haven't see one discussing my question.  I hope that's possible.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org)? It offers the following C API: http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uchar_8h.html#aa488f2a373998c7decb0ecd3e3552079

```
int32_t u_charName(
    UChar32 code,
    UCharNameChoice nameChoice,
    char* buffer,
    int32_t bufferLength,
    UErrorCode* pErrorCode)
```

> Retrieve the name of a Unicode character.
>
> Depending on `nameChoice`, the character name written into the buffer is the "modern" name or the name that was defined in Unicode version 1.0. The name contains only "invariant" characters like A-Z, 0-9, space, and '-'. Unicode 1.0 names are only retrieved if they are different from the modern names and if the data file contains the data for them. gennames may or may not be called with a command line option to include 1.0 names in unames.dat.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> > **code** The character (code point) for which to get the name. It must be `0<=code<=0x10ffff`.
> >
> > **nameChoice** Selector for which name to get.
> >
> > **buffer** Destination address for copying the name. The name will always be zero-terminated. If there is no name, then the buffer will be set to the empty string.
> >
> > **bufferLength** `==sizeof(buffer)`
> >
> > **pErrorCode** Pointer to a UErrorCode variable; check for U_SUCCESS() after u_charName() returns.
>
> **Returns**
>
> > The length of the name, or 0 if there is no name for this character. If the bufferLength is less than or equal to the length, then the buffer contains the truncated name and the returned length indicates the full length of the name. The length does not include the zero-termination.

Comment: Thanks.  I have never heard of it.  That's good to know.  I prefer not to use somebody else's tool unless there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

ICU is the right approach, but it's even simpler than Chris said.  Foundation includes ICU already, for various text processing functions, including [CFStringTransform()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1542411-cfstringtransform).  Its `transform` parameter accepts "any valid ICU transform ID defined in the ICU User Guide for Transforms".

One of [ICU's transforms](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general) is `Any-Name`:

> Converts between characters and their Unicode names in curly braces. For example: 
>   ., ⇆ {FULL STOP}{COMMA}

(The syntax isn't exactly as documented, but it's close enough you can figure it out.)

There's also an `Any-Hex` transform which can be used for translating to/from the codepoint hex value.