# Searching for Unicode code points by name

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, codepoint

I need a way to search for Unicode code points by the name of the code point in Swift/Objective-C on iOS. So if a user types "shade" it would find code points containing the word shade, like U+2591 through U+2593. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Here is a public index for codepoint names: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25346064/2057171

Comment: For anyone who cares, I ended up finding this link http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/NamesList.txt which I used to create a database of all the value, and I can search for values in it pretty quickly

Comment: The fact that this question was closed as "opinion based" is very odd... Voting for reopen.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to keep a database of the unicode codepoint information, indexed by name.

You're never going to make this *massively* efficient, because you're doing a "contains" search. You can't use computer-science tricks like binary search or trees to do this. Ultimately, all the names have to be walked through.

Comment: SQLite would be a very good format for this.

Comment: Here is a public index for codepoint names: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25346064/2057171

Comment: Do you know where I could get a database with all this info already in it? Or even a json file so I could use that to make an sqlite database?

Comment: The info is readily downloaded from the unicode consortium.